# Post Apocalyptic anime with characters in neon skin suits and glowing eyes

Tags: story-identification, anime

It's kind of set in a post apocalyptic world. There are these characters who wear neon skin suits and they have glowing eyes. I think they are kids being experimented on or something and also they are trying to find a source of energy.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When and where did you read this?

Comment: Welcome! Please check out [this post](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/89007) for tips on improving this question. If you can think of any further details, please [edit](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/266085/edit) them into your question.